# kendo jquery form textarea does not cater newline

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use the kendo jquery form and the code is as below:

```
$("#form").kendoForm({
    validatable: { validationSummary: true },
    orientation: "horizontal",
    formData: {
        ID: "@Model.ID",
        //blabla
        Description: "@Model.DESCRIPTION",
        CreatedBy: "@ViewBag.User_Name"
    },
    //blabla
    items: [{
            type: "group",
            label: "Edit Issue Details",
            items: [
                //blabla
                {
                    field: "Description",
                    label: "Description: ",
                    editor: function (container, options) {
                        $("<textarea class='k-textarea' rows='5' placeholder='Write your description here' required data-bind='value: " + options.field + "'></textarea>").appendTo(container);
                    },
                },
                //blabla
            ]
    }],
    //blabla
});
```

the output is fine if the value is only one line as such:

```
hello, testing, this is not a newline
```

but an error occurred whenever there's more than 1 line in the value:

```
hello,
testing
newline
```

ive tried using template but maybe im still a little bit too confused to use them now idk

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following the documentation [here](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/form/basic-usage) from Telerik first.

In the above page, here is how they create the `textarea` control:

```js
$("#exampleform").kendoForm({
    ...
    items: [{
        type: "group",
        label: "Edit Issue Details",
        items: [
            {
                field: "Description",
                label: "Description:",
                editor: "TextArea",
                editorOptions: { rows: 5 },
            },
        ]
    }],
    ...
});
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. i followed the tutorial from the documentation you shared but i still got error from the console.  it highlighted the area where ive initialized the data in `formData: {}`. i somehow bypass these by encoding the existing data in the controller and decoding them back in the javascript. not sure if this is efficient or not but its working for now.

Answer (score 0):

With the R1 of 2022 there are some changes with the CSS classes, so you need to update them to render the TextArea with the same styling as the other editors. [Here is an example](https://dojo.telerik.com/Utahibuy) of how to render multiline in a TextArea:

```
$("#form").kendoForm({
            formData: {
                Description: "hello,\ntesting\nnewline",
            },
            items: [{
                field: "Description",
                label: "Description:",
                editor: function(container, options) {
                    $("<textarea class='k-input k-textarea k-input-solid k-input-md k-rounded-md' required rows='5' name='" + options.field + "' required data-bind='value: " +  options.field + "'></textarea>")
                        .appendTo(container);
                },
                validation: { required: true }
            }],
        });
```

The TextArea is also a [built-in editor](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/form/configuration/items#itemseditor), so you can use it as @ShawnOrr suggested.